# $Z_p$-rank of universal norms

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm having some trouble with a statement in Cyclotomic Fields and Zeta Values by Coates and Sujatha. Let $K_n=\mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_{p^{n+1}})^{+}$ and let $U^1_n$ denote the principal units of $K_n$. The universal norm group is defined as $N_{\infty}(U_n^1)=\bigcap_{m \geq n}N_{m,n}(U_m^1)$ where $N_{m,n}$ is the norm from $K_m$ to $K_n$. In the proof of Theorem 4.6.3., it is implied that $N_{\infty}(U_n^1)$ has $\mathbb{Z}_p$-rank equal to $[F:\mathbb{Q}]-1$ where $F_n=\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^{n+1}})$. Since Leopoldt's conjecture is true for $F_n$, and the cyclotomic units have finite index in the group of global units for this field, it follows that the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-closure $C_n^1$ of the principal cyclotomic units has $\mathbb{Z}_p$-rank equal to $[F_n:\mathbb{Q}]-1$. Since $C_n^1 \subset N_{\infty}(U_n^1)$, we have a lower bound on the rank. ( In the proof of the aforementioned theorem, it is asserted that this quotient is finite). On the other hand, $U_n^1$ has $\mathbb{Z}_p$-rank equal to $[F_n:\mathbb{Q}]$ via the $\log$ map. This gives us an upper bound. What's making this more confusing is that while trying to figure this out on my own, I came across another paper, asserting that the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-rank of $N_{\infty}(U_n^1)$ is actually $[F_n:\mathbb{Q}]$. I'm sure there is something I'm not seeing. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. By local class field theory $U_n^1/N_{\infty}(U_n^1) \cong G(K_{\infty}/K_n)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$. As mentioned in my post $U_n^1$ has $\mathbb{Z}_p$-rank = $[F_n:\mathbb{Q}]$ so the result follows.